# mysql distance calculation using lat & long

Tags: mysql

I find the lat & long using php

From address: [202 Roat St, Ithaca, NY, United States](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=202%20Roat%20St,%20Ithaca,%20NY,%20United%20States&sensor=false)

Lat:42.466004
Long:-76.469566

To address : [344 Elmira Rd, Ithaca, NY, United States](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=344%20Elmira%20Rd,%20Ithaca,%20NY,%20United%20States&sensor=false)

Lat:42.424604
Long:-76.514676

Using php get the lat & long of customer want to search address

```
list($find_lat,$find_long) = $this->findLatLongFromAddress($res_address);
```

I am using this query

```
SELECT restaurant_id, restaurant_name, ROUND( ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( 42.466004 ) ) * cos( radians( restaurant_lat ) ) * cos( radians( restaurant_long ) - radians( - 76.469566 ) ) + sin( radians( 42.466004 ) ) * sin( radians( restaurant_lat ) ) ) ) , 2 ) AS distance, restaurant_delivery_distance
FROM rt_restaurant
WHERE restaurant_lat != ''
AND restaurant_long != ''
```

I am getting the distance as 3.67 miles from query. this is wrong from query.

But I am searching from google map with internet using these 2 address. Its getting the distance as  7.2 miles

Kindly help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The results from these two cannot be compared.!

Answer (score 1):

That is simply because Google Maps will show you the travel distance (in car for example). Your MySQL query calculation will show you the [line of sight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-of-sight) distance.

Your query is working, but the results can't be compared. Also, you will not be able to calculate the trip distance by yourself unless you keep a database with roads and have an algorithm like Google Map have.